# PHP Mail how to show success box on page

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am new to PHP, and I made this PHP Mail, for a regular contact form... When the form is completed, the page is redirected and displays "The message was sent succesfully". The problem is, i don't want the page to redirect.. I want to show a feedback on the index, something like a success modal box or a simple text underneath the form "your message was sent"...

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emaildestino = 'contato@zerodesign.com.br';
$email_from='contato@zerodesign.com.br';
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$titulo = 'Mensagem - TESTE';




 <?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emaildestino = 'contato@zerodesign.com.br';
$email_from='contato@zerodesign.com.br';
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$titulo = 'Mensagem - TESTE';




$juntando = '<p>Esta mensagem foi enviada pelo site</p><br/>
<p><b>Nome:</b> '.$nome.'</b></p><br>
<p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.' </b></p><br>
<p><b>Telefone:</b> '.$telefone.'</p> </br>
<p><b>Mensagem:</b></p>
<p><i>'.$mensagem.'</i></p>
<hr>';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= "From: $email_from " . "\n";

$envio = mail($emaildestino, $titulo, $juntando, $headers, "-r".$email_from);

if($envio)
echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";
else
 echo "A mensagem nãpode ser enviada";
 ?>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="envia.php"> 
<p><input id="inputt" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" ></p>
<p><input  id="inputt" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"></p>
<p><input class="inputt" type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone">     </p>
<p><textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea></p>


<input id="button" type="submit" value="Enviar"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `action` attribute empty like...

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="">
```

So, the page will submit to itself.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tested with single quotes, and its still redirecting to a blank white page, containing only the text "email was sent succesfuly"

Comment: i want to show a little text, on the main page, just a simples feedback underneath the contact form... or maybe a modal div with the text "sent succesfully"

Comment: But I just added that text. it should show, either text based on the fact, if the image was sent or not

Comment: but withou redirectin... when the client press "send", automatically the little text shows up

Comment: There is NO redirection on your script. so, it you press send, the page will remain where it is

Comment: I see... would you kindly see my website and send a message, for you to understand what i'm trying to do? www.zerodesign.com.br

Comment: Ok, in that case, make action empty like `action=''` So, PHP will submit to its own page, and will not go the `envia.php`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you want to do is not visit the envia.php page, you'll need to send an AJAX call there instead. When the ajax call finishes, you can use javascript to update your index page with the success message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like:

PHP script added to the top of the form page redirecting to the same page

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['mensagem'], $_POST['assunto'], $_POST['telefone']){
    ...
    $envio = mail($emaildestino, $titulo, $juntando, $headers, "-r".$email_from);
    if($envio){
        $msg = "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";
    }else{
        $msg = "A mensagem nãpode ser enviada";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>"> 
    <p><input id="inputt" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" id="nome" ></p>
    <p><input  id="inputt" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"></p>
    <p><input class="inputt" type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone">     </p>
    <p><textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea></p>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Enviar"><br>
    <span id="msg"><?php if(isset($msg)){echo $msg;}?></span>
</form>
```

looking at your site you might want to add the `<?php if(isset($msg)){echo $msg;}?>` to the top of the page or add a js script that scrolls to the bottom of the page